# Joined query missing records

Tags: mysql

I have a database that contains a people table and another table with names for those people. For each person, there is at least one record in the names table, with one of those being set as the 'person_default_name_id' for that person, but other variations of that name in different languages. The idea is that the user who looks up the table will have a preferred language set (e.g. English, Spanish, Russian) and a preferred script set, which is based on their preferred language (e.g. if their preferred language is English or Spanish, the script would be "Latin", while if the preferred language is Russian, the script would be "Cyrillic"). It's a little complex and I'm wanting to display a list of names, but only display one name per person, and that one chosen name should be shown according to the best-fit for the user's chosen language and script.

The code below is what I'm trying:

```sql
SELECT 
    people.person_id,
    names.name
FROM 
    `people` 
LEFT JOIN
    `names` ON names.person_id=people.person_id
LEFT JOIN
    `languages` ON names.language_id = languages.language_id
LEFT JOIN
    `language_scripts` ON languages.language_id = language_scripts.language_id
WHERE 
    (
    /* 1st preference - display the default name for the person IF the default name's language writing system matches the user's writing system */
    (people.person_default_name_id=names.name_id AND language_scripts.script_id = :user_script_id)
    OR
    /* 2nd preference - display the alternative name in the user's chosen language if an alternative name exists in that language */
    names.language_id = :user_language_id
    OR
    /* 3rd preference - display the alternative name in the user's chosen writing system if an alternative name exists in that writing system */
    language_scripts.script_id = :user_script_id
    )
GROUP BY 
    people.person_id 
ORDER BY 
    names.name ASC
```

Example data is below:

#### Table: people

```
 person_id | person_default_name_id
------------------------------------
 1         | 2
```

#### Table: names

```
 name_id | name   | person_id | language_id
--------------------------------------------
 1       | George | 1         | 1
 2       | Jorge  | 1         | 2
 3       | Джордж | 1         | 3
```

#### Table: languages

```
 language_id | language
------------------------
 1           | English
 2           | Spanish
 3           | Russian
```

#### Table: language_scripts

```
 language_script_id | language_id | script_id
----------------------------------------------
 1                  | 1           | 1
 2                  | 2           | 1
 3                  | 3           | 2
```

#### Table: scripts

```
 script_id | script
----------------------
 1         | Latin
 2         | Cyrillic
```

I'm finding that some of the expected records are not coming through. I'm guessing that there are improvements I could make to my query, but my skills are not quite advanced enough to know the best path. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please check your join with names table, there is no person_id with in names table. It should be name_id as i understand. Your requirement is a bit conditional. like you want if......do this......else do this.......usually i do this type of solution in PHP (any programming language) rather than with database (specially mysql).

Comment: `usually i do this type of solution in PHP` Using PHP to implement massive amount of if else is tremendously slower, I would recommend stick with SQL as used in the question

Comment: Hi @dollas, your SQL is missing something, this is missing `names.software_title_language_id`, can you add back in the columns?

Comment: @MohitSaini Thanks for pointing out the omission. I do have names.person_id in the actual table but just forgot to copy it across to my question.

Comment: @NgSekLong Thanks for your response. names.software_title_language_id was a mistake I made when typing out this question (I was working on two things at once!). In the actual query, it's names.language_id

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you put your where clause conditions in your select statement and return a "score" for each record.  Remove it entirely from your where clause and it may give you insight into why you have missing records if they are returned with a 0 score.

Case when condition Then 5
          when condition then 4
          Etc...
          else 0
End case

Once you have your results scored, you can order by your score descending and take the first one per person.   Or add additional outer queries to only return the rows having the max score per person.

Apologies for answering from my phone.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Using cases and outer queries are new to me. Would you happen to know of some good examples I could look at that demonstrate your suggestion?

Comment: Building upon this, I've opened a new question as I'm now encountering difficulties with the outer query suggestion and thought it would be best if posted separately. The new question can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185690/mysql-applying-an-outer-join-to-a-complex-statement

Comment: dallas1, since you started a new question based on my suggestion, do me a solid and upvote my answer!

Comment: Have done, but as I have a reputation score of less than 15 it does not show publicly.