# mysql - Applying an outer join to a complex statement

Tags: mysql, case, outer-join

I put together a query to pull out peoples' names, giving preference to the version of that name that is written in the language/writing script of the person viewing the page.

I was having some troubles with missing records earlier, and posted a question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56747014/joined-query-missing-records). I received an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56747532/11695464) that suggested using a CASE statement and applying a score to rank the names based on the preferred language/script. I've gotten as far as the ranking, which has allowed the correct number of records to be returned (no missing records now). See below:

```
SELECT 
    people.person_id,
    names.name,
CASE 
    WHEN people.person_default_name_id=names.name_id AND language_scripts.script_id = :user_script_id THEN 3
    WHEN names.language_id = :user_language_id THEN 2
    WHEN language_scripts.script_id = :user_script_id THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END as score
FROM 
    `people` 
LEFT JOIN
    `names` ON names.person_id=people.person_id
LEFT JOIN
    `languages` ON names.language_id = languages.language_id
LEFT JOIN
    `language_scripts` ON languages.language_id = language_scripts.language_id
GROUP BY 
    people.person_id 
ORDER BY 
    names.name ASC
```

The trouble I'm now having is that, because I just need one result per person (hence the GROUP BY), it's simply pulling out the first record it encounters per person. I need to be able to put the "score" to work and only pull out the record with the highest available score (which could be 3, 2, 1 or 0) -- the one record per person with the highest score.

The suggestion in the original post was to use an outer query, but I'm not sure how to apply that here. Any ideas?

EDIT: This fiddle shows an example that pulls out all records with their scores: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54ce8/13 -- what I want to be able to do is to just draw out the one record per person_id that has the highest score. In this example, I'd like a table with Jorge and Alejandro only as they are the highest scored names for each of the two.

Comment: enclose the `CASE` expression in a `MAX()` aggregate function i.e.  `MAX(CASE WHEN ... END) AS max_score`

Comment: Thanks for your response, @spencer7593. I tried that, but all it seems to do is display the maximum possible score for each record (i.e. 3), but not necessarily the name that corresponds with that score.

Comment: I've put together a fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54ce8/13
This shows all of the records being pulled out with their corresponding score. What I want to be able to do is to just draw out the one record per person_id that has the highest score. In this example, I'd like a table with Jorge and Alejandro only as they are the highest scored names for each of the two people.

Comment: Hi @tcadidot0, yes that's correct. The result should be Jorge and Alejandro *because* they have the highest score. If Jorge and Alejandro were not present in the names table, then George and Alexander with a score of 2 would be the result instead as they are the next highest score.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment because I didn't read your full question. I think you should make the query above as a sub-query without any `GROUP BY` then join it with your `names` table. That should give you the correct name

Comment: Wait.. I just tested that and it doesn't seem right. Let me try something and get back to you soon.

Comment: @dallas1 , `3` will be the maximum score or will you have any other score more than that?

Comment: Thanks, @tcadidot0. 3 will be the maximum.

Comment: @dallas1 what if there are two names in same `person_id` have the highest score?

Comment: It's unlikely there would be multiple names that conform to the same requirements. If there were, it would suggest there's a duplicate in the database. In that case, it should just use the first one found.

Comment: Ok, another question, what if there's no record of `person_id` scoring 3? Maybe a `person_id` highest score is only 2.

Comment: The idea would be to  get whatever is the highest ranking record, so if 3 does not exist, it gets the record that scored 2. If there's no record with a 2, it gets the one that scored 1, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only think of one way to achieve this. With a combination of `GROUP_CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` on your current working query. Example query below:

```
SELECT    person_id,
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(a.name ORDER BY a.score DESC),',',1) sname, 
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(a.score ORDER BY a.score DESC),',',1) max_score FROM 
(SELECT   people.person_id,
          names.name,
          CASE 
          WHEN people.person_default_name_id=names.name_id AND language_scripts.script_id = '1' THEN 3
          WHEN names.language_id = '1' THEN 2
          WHEN language_scripts.script_id = '1' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
          END AS score
FROM      `people` 
LEFT JOIN `names` ON names.person_id=people.person_id
LEFT JOIN `languages` ON names.language_id = languages.language_id
LEFT JOIN `language_scripts` ON languages.language_id = language_scripts.language_id) a 
GROUP BY person_id;
```

I did test the query in the fiddle as well http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54ce8/33

A bit of explanation:

1. `GROUP_CONCAT` over the name & score with addition of `ORDER BY` condition - note that the `ORDER BY` must be identical in both of the `GROUP_CONCAT`.
2. `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get the first value separated by comma (,) in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Is returning the `score` important? Or is the goal to just return a `name` that satisfies the condition for score=3, and if that doesn't exist, the return a `name` that satisfies the condition for score=2, else ...

One way to do that would be to do conditional aggregation, to return value of `name` when a condition is met, else return NULL, then pick out the non-NULL value with a `MAX()` (or `MIN()` aggregate function.

We could then use a `COALESCE` function to give us the first non-NULL value, checking if we get a score=3 row, then a score=2 row, etc.

```
SELECT p.person_id
     , COALESCE(
         MAX(CASE
               WHEN p.person_default_name_id = n.name_id AND s.script_id = '1'  
               THEN n.name
               ELSE NULL 
         END)
       , MAX(CASE
               WHEN n.language_id = '1'
               THEN n.name
               ELSE NULL 
         END)
       , MAX(CASE
                WHEN s.script_id = '1'
                THEN n.name
                ELSE NULL
          END)
       , MAX(n.name)
       ) AS `name`

       -- additional expressions so we can see what is happening
     , MAX(CASE
             WHEN p.person_default_name_id = n.name_id AND s.script_id = '1'  
             THEN n.name
             ELSE NULL 
       END) AS s3_name
     , MAX(CASE
             WHEN n.language_id = '1'
             THEN n.name
             ELSE NULL 
             END
       ) AS s2_name
     , MAX(CASE
          WHEN s.script_id = '1'
          THEN n.name
          ELSE NULL 
          END) AS s1_name
     , MAX(n.name) AS s0_name

  FROM `people` p
  LEFT
  JOIN `names` n
    ON n.person_id = p.person_id
  LEFT
  JOIN `languages` l
    ON l.language_id = n.language_id
  LEFT
  JOIN `language_scripts` s
    ON s.language_id = l.language_id
 GROUP
    BY p.person_id
 ORDER
    BY ...
```

Demonstration here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54ce8/37

Comment: Returning the score is not important - it's just a way of getting the most relevant name, as you've noted in your first paragraph.

This code also works well. Thank you very much!